# Wireless internet very slow when HD TV channel is on

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, cable-modem

I have cable and internet service with Comcast. I'm experiencing really slow speeds when an HD channel is on on my TV. I thought this may have to do with my splitter, but I found that this happens only when I'm using wireless though. When my laptop is directly connected to the cable modem, the speed is fine even when the HD channel is on.

My setup is this:

- Cable from the wall is connected to a splitter.
- The other end of the splitter, from one side, a cable goes into the internet cable modem.
- From the other it goes to my TV Comcast Cable box (HD).
- Ethernet cable goes from my cable modem to my D-Link wireless router.
- An Ethernet cable goes from my wireless router to a PlayStation.
- And another cable goes to a Vonage device.

What could be the problem? How is my wireless getting affected when my TV channel is on? I don't see any relation here.

Comment: What happens if the laptop is right next to the router, but on WiFi?

Answer (score 2):

I have had issues with a wireless router that was sitting next to a transformer. There's probably some interference messing with your wireless signal. I would try and move the router much further from your TV equipment and see if you still have the problem.